# Parallel processing not working using create_app in julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, packagecompiler.jl

So I'm using the create_app() method in PackageCompiler to create an app of my julia package. It works except that the original package could run on multiple processes and after it's turned into and app it doesn't anymore.

I put this at the beginning of my script (and in the app main function)

```
@info("using $(nworkers()) workers\n")
```

It outputs whatever I pass with the -p flag when running the script indicating it is indeed running with multiple workers. After the package is turned into an app it always prints "using 1 workers" regardless of the flags I pass using --julia-args -pX

Is there something that I should enable to make this work, or is this inherently not possible?

cheers

jiq

UPDATE: it seems that using addprocs() does work (which provides a workaround for me) but I'm still confused as to why the command line argument -p is not picked up